# Connecting RDS across VPCs without Peering

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc

I am trying to connect to my RDS SQL Instance in one of my VPCs private subnet from anothe VPCs private subnet without peering(all in same region) - Is there a way to use vpc private links ?

Comment: I doubt you'd find a more straightforward and more recommended way for *cross-vpc access* in your case: It uses private IPs. Also it is no SPOF, there is no bandwidth bottleneck etc. Tell more why peering is non-grata?

Comment: Agreed. Perfect use-case for VPC Peering.